# Unable to upload APK without BILLING permissions from Manifest

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

I recently deleted and removed all BILLING related code from my app, including all in-app purchases from the Console. There are no in-app products or subscriptions.

I also removed this line to avoid having 'Offers in-app purchases' in on my Play Store listing. 
`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`

However, when I try to upload my apk, I get the error:

`Warnings
You uploaded an APK that does not have BILLING permission, or has a BILLING permission that is limited to specific sdk versions. BILLING permission is required for selling in-app products.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: uncheck contains in-app purchases from play store

Comment: @AbhishekSingh where is this in the console?

Comment: yes in developer console

Comment: @AbhishekSingh im in Store Presence > Store Listing and i dont see this check box

Comment: I think it's related to the Google Play Console settings.
In the Google Play Console try to remove all your in-app products in this way:
Store presence -> In-App products, click on each item and click "Remove" in the top right corner.
Then when you don't have any item in the list, try to reupload the APK.

Comment: @ono did you get solutions for this warning? I found same issue.

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel its just a warning. you can still post your apk.

Comment: i have exactly same warning. what was your solution?

Comment: @batmaci just a warning, didn't see any issues with it.

Comment: you are right. it is just strange that this warning appears